# Dynamically addressing kml in Google Earth API for Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm using [Google Earth API for Google Maps v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html) to display kml files in a window which can then be switched between Maps and Earth browsers. This is a different plugin to that officially provided by Google, and I've run into a problem dynamically switching kml in the Earth window. I use checkboxes to switch them in the Maps API V3, window, but when the browser is switched to Earth it no longer listens to the checkbox actions. Essentially what I'm trying to do is a replication of the interactive checkbox example on the google code playground, but I think I should be using the Maps V3 scripts?

I've included a link to the example script here:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/webgistank/TRMM_Checkbox_Example.html

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Regards,
Kerry

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your code. For example, the line

```
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addOverlays);
```

references the non-existent function `addOverlays`

Also, I'm not sure what you mean...

> "This is a different plugin to that officially provided by Google"

...as it is the *exact same* plugin.

You also state that...

> "...it no longer listens to the checkbox actions."

It is the browser listens for the actions, not the Earth plug-in. The checkboxs event are still firing, the reason the code doesn't work is that the "Google Earth Api" (the api for controlling the plugin) uses totally different objects and methods to the Google Maps Api (the api for controlling the map). Things like `google.maps.KmlLayer` just don't exist in the Earth Api at all. So when the checkbox event fires it causes and error because you are calling methods on objects that don't exist.

From looking at your code, after initialising the Earth plugin via

```
googleEarth = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

You don't do anything else with it...You mention in your question the [interactive checkbox example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#fetch_kml_%28interactive,_checkboxes%29) on the Google code playground, but as far as I can see you haven't actually implemented any of the code from that example.

Take another look at the function `loadKml` method in that example - it clearly shows how to load and display data in the Earth plugin.